# Sequence of sequences on an arbitrary metric space

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $(x^{(n)})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $X^{\mathbb{N}}$, that is, a sequence of sequences. Define a metric on $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ by
\begin{equation}
d'(x^{(n)}, x) := \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} \frac{d(x_k^{(n)}, x_k)}{1 + d(x_k^{(n)}, x_k)}
\end{equation}
Show that if $x_{k}^{(n)} \to x_k$ for each $k$, i.e., for all $k$ and for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N_k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n \geq N_k$ then $d(x_k^{(n)}, x_k) < \epsilon$, then $x^{(n)} \to x$ where $x := (x_k)_{k=1}^{\infty} \in X^{\mathbb{N}}$.

I thought maybe I should try to get a uniform $N$ that works for all $k$ but I realised shortly after that a maximum or supremum need not exist and now I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$1).\ $ Choose $N$ so large that $\sum^{\infty}_{k=N} \frac{1}{2^k}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and then

$2).\ $ Note that For each $1\le k\le N-1$ there is an $n_k$ such that $d(x_k^{(n)}, x_k)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ as soon as $n>n_k.$ Now

$3).\ $ Consider the sum $ \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{2^k} \frac{d(x_k^{(n)}, x_k)}{1 + d(x_k^{(n)}, x_k)}.$